# Setting up a chromium-like sandbox (error 0xc00000a5)

Tags: c++, windows, security, sandbox

I'm trying to setup a sandbox akin to [chromium](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox). In particular, I'm trying to replicate their trick of creating a sleeping process with a low-privilege token, then setting a high-privilege token temporarily before running it. The idea is to let the process do all its initialization in high-privilege mode, then reverting to the low-privilege token right before running any unsafe code.

So far, I'm struggling just to get a basic test up and running. Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <AccCtrl.h>
#include <aclapi.h>

#define VERIFY(x) { bool r = x; assert(r); }

uint8_t* GetTokenInfo(const HANDLE& token, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS info_class, DWORD* error)
{
    // Get the required buffer size.
    DWORD size = 0;
    ::GetTokenInformation(token, info_class, NULL, 0, &size);
    if (!size)
    {
        *error = ::GetLastError();
        return nullptr;
    }

    uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[size];
    if (!::GetTokenInformation(token, info_class, buffer, size, &size))
    {
        *error = ::GetLastError();
        return nullptr;
    }

    *error = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    // Open the current token
    CHandle processToken;
    VERIFY(::OpenProcessToken(::GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &processToken.m_h));

    // Create an impersonation token without restrictions
    HANDLE impersonationToken;
    VERIFY(DuplicateToken(processToken, SecurityImpersonation, &impersonationToken));

    // Build the list of the deny only group SIDs
    DWORD error;
    uint8_t* buffer = GetTokenInfo(processToken, TokenGroups, &error);
    if (!buffer) return error;

    TOKEN_GROUPS* token_groups = reinterpret_cast<TOKEN_GROUPS*>(buffer);
    std::vector<SID*> sids_for_deny_only;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < token_groups->GroupCount; ++i)
    {
        if ((token_groups->Groups[i].Attributes & SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY) == 0 &&
            (token_groups->Groups[i].Attributes & SE_GROUP_LOGON_ID) == 0)
        {
            sids_for_deny_only.push_back(reinterpret_cast<SID*>(token_groups->Groups[i].Sid));
        }
    }

    {
        DWORD size = sizeof(TOKEN_USER) + SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE;
        uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[size];
        TOKEN_USER* token_user = reinterpret_cast<TOKEN_USER*>(buffer);
        BOOL result = ::GetTokenInformation(processToken, TokenUser, token_user, size, &size);

        if (!result) return ::GetLastError();
        sids_for_deny_only.push_back(reinterpret_cast<SID*>(token_user->User.Sid));
    }

    size_t deny_size = sids_for_deny_only.size();
    SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES *deny_only_array = NULL;
    if (deny_size)
    {
        deny_only_array = new SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[deny_size];

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sids_for_deny_only.size(); ++i)
        {
            deny_only_array[i].Attributes = SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY;
            deny_only_array[i].Sid = const_cast<SID*>(sids_for_deny_only[i]);
        }
    }

    // Create restricted sids
    DWORD size_sid = SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE;
    BYTE sid_[SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE];
    VERIFY(::CreateWellKnownSid(WinNullSid, NULL, sid_, &size_sid));

    SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES sidsToRestrict[] =
    {
        reinterpret_cast<SID*>(const_cast<BYTE*>(sid_)),
        0
    };

    // Create the restricted token
    HANDLE restrictedToken;
    VERIFY(::CreateRestrictedToken(processToken,
        0, // flags
        deny_size,
        deny_only_array,
        0,
        0,
        _countof(sidsToRestrict), // number of SIDs to restrict,
        sidsToRestrict, // no SIDs to restrict,
        &restrictedToken));

    VERIFY(::IsTokenRestricted(restrictedToken));   

    // Create a process using the restricted token (but keep it suspended)
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

    VERIFY(::CreateProcessAsUser(restrictedToken,
        L"C:\\Dev\\Projects\\SandboxTest\\Debug\\Naughty.exe",
        0, // cmd line
        0, // process attributes
        0, // thread attributes
        FALSE, // don't inherit handles
        CREATE_SUSPENDED | DETACHED_PROCESS, // flags
        0, // inherit environment
        0, // inherit current directory
        &startupInfo,
        &processInfo));

    // Set impersonation token with more rights
    {
        HANDLE temp_thread = processInfo.hThread;
        if (!::SetThreadToken(&temp_thread, impersonationToken))
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Run the process
    if (!::ResumeThread(processInfo.hThread)) // Other process crashes immediately when this is run
    {
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Not quite sure about deny list and restrict list yet, but if I understand this correctly it should be irrelevant. I'm calling SetThreadToken with my unrestricted token before running the thread, so I figure it should not matter what settings I use for restrictedToken. However, this is not the case; the new process crashes with the error code 0xc00000a5. If I use processToken instead of restrictedToken in CreateProcessAsUser, the code runs just fine. It's like SetThreadToken isn't doing anything.

I'm not doing much in naughty.exe right now, just starting an infinite loop.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit 1:**
According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) page, 0xc00000a5 means "STATUS_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL". Not sure on this, but I think I'm missing SeImpersonatePrivilege, causing stuff to fail. Still investigating options...

**Edit 2:**
Okay, seems like I had to reduce the privilege of the impersonation token to be able to use it with the other process. Not sure why, but not I can run the program without admin rights.

Still getting an error though :/ Now it's "STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND". Best lead from examining Process Monitor logs is an ACCESS DENIED on "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll". The weird part is that it seems to be working once in a while (i.e. the spawned process sometimes runs just fine). Back to digging...

Comment: Why don't you look at their code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the startup code trying to load the C runtime DLL from a new thread (which doesn't have access to the high-privilege token). What worked for me is to statically link the CRT into the sandbox process (i.e. `/MTd` in Debug builds, `/MT` in Release builds).

Answer (score 1):

> the new process crashes with the error code 0xc00000a5 / STATUS_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL

I've encountered this when:

1. the restricted token specifies `SidsToRestrict` that the permissive token does not.
2. the restricted token specifies a lower integrity level than the permissive token.

- "restricted": The more restrictive token passed to `CreateProcessAsUser`
- "permissive": The less restrictive token passed to `SetThreadToken`, and used until that thread calls `RevertToSelf`

It appears you cannot un**restrict** sids or raise the integrity level with `SetThreadToken`, even if the parent process is unrestricted in these regards - you can only un**deny** sids, or unremove **privileges**.

> I had to reduce the privilege of the impersonation token to be able to use it with the other process

This was a red herring for me.  I tried every combination of keeping/removing privilige LUIDs for the permissive and restrictive tokens with little effect.

> 0xC0000135 / STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND
>
> Best lead from examining Process Monitor logs is an ACCESS DENIED on "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll". The weird part is that it seems to be working once in a while (i.e. the spawned process sometimes runs just fine).

The DLL loading/initializing code appears to be multithreaded.  Speculating a bit here, my **theory** is that the new threads don't inherit the permissive token specified by `SetThreadToken`, and that `ucrtbased.dll` only loads successfully if the initial/main thread happened to be the thread that loaded `ucrtbased.dll`, and will fail if it's instead loaded by any of the worker threads - hence why it works sometimes, but typically not.

Workaround options:

1. Statically link the CRT.  This is my current preference.
2. Don't pass `Everyone` or `Users` to `SidsToDisable`.  Defeats the point of denying sids for sandboxing purposes in the first place, so I'd recommend against this, especially since I see no way to disable them later.
3. Have the parent process listen for [`CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/debugging-events) and `SetThreadToken` for them too?  I haven't tested this, but I suspect it might work.  Would only want to do this during startup, lest you break open the sandbox after the child process has called `RevertToSelf()` etc.

> 0xC0000142 / ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED

Okay, this one's just me: I encountered this when trying to spawn a process at `Untrusted` integrity when initializing `bcrypt.dll` for Rust's stdlib.  Spawn at `Low` instead, and have the child process lower itself to `Untrusted` post-init IMO.

> How the heck do you use `SidsToRestrict` at all then?

You can't go from nullptr restrictions on a permissive token to real restrictions on a restricted token without causing `0xc00000a5 / STATUS_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL`.

However, you *can* go from one restriction list to another, and neither necessairly needs to contain all the exact same SIDs as the other.

With a restrictive `SidsToRestrict` of only `S-1-0-0` "NULL SID", I can use a permissive `SidsToRestrict` containing only:

- `S-1-1-0` "Everyone" (otherwise child dies w/ `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`)
- `S-1-5-5-x-yyyyyyy` "LogonSessionId_..." (otherwise dies w/ `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED`?)

Perhaps S-1-0-0 is considered a subset of Everyone, or perhaps the restricted sids can be outright disjoint?
Using all group SIDs marked SE_GROUP_ENABLED | SE_GROUP_LOGON_ID for your permissive token might be more appropriate.

Note that the child can't lower it's integrity level unless it can `OpenProcessToken(.., ADJUST_DEFAULT, ..)` based on the current access token.
The only overlap between the permissive token's restriction sids, and the restricted *default* `TokenDefaultDacl`, is the logon session, which doesn't grant write access by default:

```
ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE { Mask: GENERIC_ALL,                    Sid: S-1-5-21-xxxx-yyyy-zzzz "%USERNAME%", .. }
ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE { Mask: GENERIC_ALL,                    Sid: S-1-5-18                "SYSTEM", .. }
ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE { Mask: GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_EXECUTE, Sid: S-1-5-5-x-yyyyyyyyy     "LogonSessionId_x_yyyyyyyyy, .. }
```

So you may want to create a new default dacl for the restricted token with:

```cpp
InitializeAcl(...);
AddAccessAllowedAce(acl, ACL_REVISION, TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT | ..., logon_session_sid);
TOKEN_DEFAULT_DACL default_dacl = { acl };
SetTokenInformation(restriced, TokenDefaultDacl, &default_dacl, sizeof(default_dacl));
```

And ensure you adjust your child process's process token integrity level *before* calling `RevertToSelf`.